# Semi-analytic (analytic ?) form for circle integral

Tags: integration

Does anybody here have an idea on how to tackle an integral of the form
$$
\int \frac{x-y}{|x-y|} \text{d}\sigma_{C(r)} (x)
$$
where $\sigma_{C(r)}$ is the Lebesgue measure on the circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ of radius $r$ and of center the origin, and where $y$ is some point in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (which might be outside, inside, or over the circle, whatever !). Are there semi-analytic formula for those kind of integrals ?

Thanks a lot for any insight !

Answer (score 1):

Let $S_r = \{x \in \mathbf{R}^2: |x| = r\}$ and $y \in S_r$, then we see that
\begin{align}
\int_{S_r} \frac{x_1-y_1}{|x-y|}d\sigma(x) =& \int^{2\pi}_0 \frac{r\cos\theta-r\cos\varphi}{\sqrt{(r\cos\theta-r\cos\varphi)^2+(r\sin\theta-r\sin\varphi)^2}} rd\theta \\
=& \frac{r}{\sqrt{2}}\int^{2\pi}_0 \frac{\cos\theta-\cos\varphi}{\sqrt{1-\cos(\theta-\varphi)}}\ d\theta\\
=&\ \frac{r}{\sqrt{2}}\int^{2\pi}_0 \frac{\cos(\theta+\varphi)-\cos\varphi}{\sqrt{1-\cos(\theta)}} d\theta\\
=&\ \frac{r}{2}\int^{2\pi}_0 \frac{-2\sin\left( \frac{\theta}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}+\varphi\right)}{\sin(\frac{\theta}{2})} d\theta\\
=&\ -r\int^{2\pi}_0 \sin(\frac{\theta}{2}+\varphi) d\theta = -4r\cos\varphi.
\end{align}
The same argument shows that
\begin{align}
\int_{S_r} \frac{x_2-y_2}{|x-y|}d\sigma(x) =& -4r\sin\varphi.
\end{align}

This means
\begin{align}
\int_{S_r} \frac{x-y}{|x-y|} d\sigma(x) = -4y.
\end{align}

If $y$ is inside the circle, then $\frac{x-y}{|x-y|}$ does not have any discontinuity. If fact, it is not hard to see that the integral vanishes since $\frac{x-y}{|x-y|}$ makes one complete turn.

I will finish the case when $y$ is outside later since I have to run.